# About a little hole in Z'ha'dum

Tags: babylon-5

Ok, so if I remember it correctly:

> The part of Kosh that was in Sheridan told him to jump because he knew that Lorien was in Z'ha'dum. Sheridan jumped and is grabbed by Lorien. After he replied Lorien's question correctly (why do you want live or something similar), Lorien released Sheridan only to fail to grab it again. Sheridan died and Lorien had to pass part of his live to Sheridan.

So, why did he have to release this character only to try to grab him again and fail? I dont understand it.

Comment: As I mentioned before, dumping the entire question behind a spoiler tag strongly suggests that youve not giveb enough thought to which bits are spoilers. For example, John and Lorien (or rather their actors)  both appear in the credits. We know that John was on Zhadum in the previous episode, etc.

Comment: @Valorum: I am new here. Still learning.

Comment: I believe that the question that Lorien asked John was "Do you have anything worth living for?"

Comment: Even the title of this question would have been a minor spoiler in 1994.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that you've fundamentally misunderstood this episode. Lorien hasn't caught John in *mid-air*, he's caught John's soul ([which is a thing in the B5 universe](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Soul)) as it departs his dying body, wrecked by the fall and the nuclear bomb a few miles above.

It's not until Lorien returns his soul to his body and repairs the damage that John is revived. He doesn't need to physically 'catch' him a second time because he's already on the ground. Note that Lorien isn't even that sure that he'll be able to save him.

> **Lorien:** *I caught you before.*
>
> **John:** *What if I die?*
>
> **Lorien:** *I can not create life, but **I can breathe on the remaining embers**.. It may not work.*
>
> **John:** *But I can hope.*

Comment: Perhaps I was confused for the image of Lorien grabbing Sheridan; it isnt his body that is falling but his soul that is leaving her body.
It could be that it has been lost in translation because I watched it in spanish.

That makes sense.

Thanks.